# Filter a SQL-View by referenced data

Tags: sql, sql-server

A have defined a **View** in **SQL-Server 2014**, which should display a list of **Vehicles**. These **Vehicles** are contained in **Invoices**. Proposing that each **Vehicle** and **Invoice** contains an **ID**, I want to select only the **Vehicle** which is contained in a specific **Invoice**.

So far so good, but the problem is that I only can filter the **View** data, not the SQL itself, i.e. I need to filter for the **ID** of the **Invoice** on the **Vehicle-View**. The **Vehicle-View** must therefore provide an information about the referenced **Invoices**, so that I can do something like that:

```
select      v.vehicle_id,
            v.vehicle_name,
            ...
from        dbo.Vehicle
where       v.invoice_id = 'XYZ'
```

Is there a possibility to do that, e.g. with a kind of aggregation without providing duplicate entries by using a normal **INNER JOIN**? An **INNER JOIN** would obviously cause a **Vehicle** to be displayed multiply times if it is contained in more than one **Invoices**. It should also be possible to show all **Vehicles** without providing an **Invoice-ID** filter.

**EDIT 1:**

```
VehicleId | VehicleName
1 | TestCar1
2 | TestCar2
3 | TestCar3
```

---

```
InvoiceId | VehicleId
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 3
5 | 3
```

Expected output of **Vehicles-View** without a filter:

```
VehicleId | VehicleName
1 | TestCar1
2 | TestCar2
3 | TestCar3
```

Expected output of **Vehicles-View** with a filter for **Invoice-ID == 1**:

```
VehicleId | VehicleName
1 | TestCar1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to join the vehicle and invoice tables together.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    v.vehicle_id,
    v.vehicle_name
FROM dbo.Vehicle v
INNER JOIN dbo.Invoice i
    ON v.VehicleId = i.VehicleId
WHERE i.InvoiceId = 1
```

If this isn't possible using your current view, then you may have to refactor it, or just not use it altogether.